# Is it possible to split the content of a PDF file with line breaks in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have a `PDF` file I want to extract the data from. Currently, I am splitting the text by lines and storing it into the `list`. I wanted to know if that's possible to somehow `split` it with that bold line break and store it on a `list`?

That bold line is a separator for each block so if that's possible then it would be easy to extract the data from this file.

The output I am after is something like this:

```
['DISTRICT ROW LLC', 'Premises No.: 0', 'License Key: 0', 'Date Entered:09/08/2021', 'Tradename: OLSEN RUN WINERY', 'Email Address: rachel@olsenrun.com', 'License Type/Action:  F-COM/ N/O', ]
```

[image]

Current code:

```
import re
import pdftotext
import csv


with open('data.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_headers = [
        'Name', 'Date Entered', 'Tradename', 'Address', 'Email Address', 'License Type/Action' 
    ]
    csv_writer.writerow(csv_headers)
        
    with open('pdf_file.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(pdf_file)
    
    lines = pdf[0][313:].split('\n')
    new_list = []
    count = 1
    for line in lines:
        new_list.append(line)
        count += 1
        if count % 8 == 0:
            name = ''
            date_entered = re.findall(r'Date Entered: (.[0-9]\/.[0-9]\/.[0-9].[0-9]?)', "".join(new_list))
            trade_name = re.findall(r'Tradename: (.*[A-Z]?)(?<=  ).*', "".join(new_list))
            address = re.findall(r'Tradename: (.*[A-Z]?)(?<=  ).*', "".join(new_list))
            email = ''
            license_type_or_action = ''
            
            new_list.clear()
```

Some output:

```
['DISTRICT ROW LLC\r', '   Premises No.: 0           License Key:   0                                  Date Entered: 09/08/2021\r', '    Tradename: OLSEN RUN WINERY                                               Date Received: 09/03/2021\r', '        Address: 32900 DIAMOND HILL DR, HARRISBURG 97446\r', '  Email Address: rachel@olsenrun.com\r', 'License Type/Action: F-COM / N/O\r', '\r']
```

Comment: which module are you using? if pypdf2 or 4 just extract the content of each page and then you can parse it. Worst case you need to detect each block manually, match id for each block: sequence of capital characters and wspace but no :

Comment: the pdf is a true pdf or a scan? if a scan then you need some ocr stuffs

Comment: It's an editable PDF. I am using pdftotext. Can you tell how can I match the ID for each block?

Comment: could add the text-output in your question?

Comment: I added the output...

Comment: No I meant if you could add the text output of pdftotext so I can work on it

Comment: Oh, I added my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237257/discussion-between-codewithawais-and-cards).

Comment: okay I am waiting you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf, [here](https://www.oregon.gov/olcc/lic/Docs/weekly_applications/2021/weeklyappslist_0904_0910.pdf) . I tried to open with `PyDF4` you got an annoying problem, `PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header [...]` which is still unsolved with PyPDF, probably due to bad quality of the file. So I converted to text from the shell using `pdftotext`.

I tried to find the start index of each block, with a regex criteria. Automatically you have also the end, which is the index of the next block (minus 1).

Once you have start and end index the corresponding slice will be a block.

```
import re

path_pdf = #

with open(path_pdf, 'r') as fd:
    text = fd.read()

header = """Report Date: 9/14/2021

Oregon Liquor & Cannabis Commission

Page {} of 5

Weekly Applications Received
For Entry Dates: 09/04/2021 Through 09/10/2021"""

# globally remove header - the header depends on the page number
text_header_less = text
for i in range(1, 6):
    text_header_less = text_header_less.replace(header.format(i), '')


text_header_less_lines = text_header_less.split('\n')

company_name_pattern = re.compile(r'^([A-Z]{3,})')  # at least 3 consecutive capital letters...could be better:)
start_location_company_datas = []
for i, l in enumerate(text_header_less_lines):
    if company_name_pattern.search(l) is not None:
        start_location_company_datas += [i]


company_data = []
for start, end in zip(start_location_company_datas[:-1], start_location_company_datas[1:]):
    # ! contain still empty lines - to be cleaned?
    #company_data += ['\n'.join(text_header_less_lines[start-1: end])]  # as a string
    company_data += [[text_header_less_lines[start-1: end] ]]   # as a list


for i in company_data[:2]:
    print(i)
    print('-'*20)
```

Output

```
[['', 'DISTRICT ROW LLC', 'Premises No.: 0', '', 'License Key:', '', '0', '', 'Tradename: OLSEN RUN WINERY', 'Address: 32900 DIAMOND HILL DR, HARRISBURG 97446', 'Email Address: rachel@olsenrun.com', 'License Type/Action: F-COM / N/O', '', 'Date Entered: 09/08/2021', 'Date Received: 09/03/2021', ''], ...]
```

Remark:

- final data could be cleaned by removing empty lines, extra white spaces... it depends on what are you looking for
- there is no way to group your automatically wrt the separator since invisible when extracting text

Comment: Hi, @cards. Am getting this error. "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 158: character maps to <undefined>". I used encoding='utf-8' but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @CodeWithAwais! With my solution? I converted the pdf to text from the shell, `$pdftotext file.pdf file.txt` and then worked with the txt-file as written in my solution. Be more precise on which line of code raised the error